# express-gateway : Consolidate requests

Tags: express-gateway

Is there a way to chain / consolidate multiple REST calls? For example, expose an api that would accept all order details and then when that api is called, make multiple calls for different steps like add to cart, checkout etc and when it’s all done, send a response back.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately we're not offering such feature just yet, although it's highly requested, so I feel we will start to work it kind of soon.

In meantime, you can reach almost the same feature through a plugin that you can write by yourself.